# HP Microserver Gen8 (Intel Celeron G1610T) with Ubuntu Server 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, raid

I'm looking for a small home server working with Ubuntu Server 14.04. I want to install SAMBA and a UPNP streaming server on it. I found this small HP Proliant Microserver with an Intel Celeron G1610T CPU. But I'm sure if I could install Ubuntu Server 14.04 on it, if there are no problems with the RAID controller (Smart Array B120i)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there would be a problem using Ubuntu on this hardware. HP does not *fully* support Ubuntu on this RAID controller. [Ubuntu's notes are here](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201203-10850/). Using an operating system more geared to physical hardware installation (like RHEL or CentOS) is a better option.

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/526111/installing-ubuntu-12-04-on-hp-proliant-dl380e-with-1tb-sas-drive/526227#526227

Comment: @8BitProgrammer CentOS will work, but you'll have to install it using a driver disk. Post another question here if you have issues with it.

Comment: Ok, I will inform you if some problems occurs during the installation. Thank you.